# How to read Windows Server 2008 (x64, SP2) memory dumps?

Tags: windows-server-2008, debugging, dump

My server suddenly started crashing every time I debug a chunk of code on my laptop which accesses the database on the server remotely. It's done it twice now, and I've stopped trying to debug my code until I can read the memory dumps from the server and see what happened.

Anyway, that's where I'm having troubles. I've downloaded and installed the Windows SDK for WinDbg as well as the Server 2008 RTM & SP2 Retail & Checked symbols, but WinDbg still yells at me that it doesn't have the correct symbols.

So, what do I have to do to get it to read the memory dump?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For dont have this kind of issues the better choice is not to download the Symbols.

Instead you can use a Symbols Server. This is a Microsoft place where they have saved the most recent symbols and if you configure it in your WinDbg will download the exact symbols that it needs on demand.`

You define your symbols insted of a local hard drive path, something like: srv*f:\symbols\websymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.

Check at [this link](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=221) how to configue Web Symbols on WinDbg.

Regards.